# Athena equivalent to information_schema

Tags: amazon-athena

For background, I come from a SQLServer background and make heavy use of the system tables & information_schema, to tell me all about my tables and columns.

I didn't expect the exact same power in Athena, but currently very shocked and frustrated with what little seems to be available - unless I've missed something ?

For example, 'describe mytable' - just describes 1 table at a time.
How about showing the columns for ALL tables in one result ?
It also does not output the table name, nor allow you to manually add that in as a custom column.

All the results of these "show/list/describe" commands seem to produce a text list - not a recordset, so you cannot take the results and join them to other tables or views to make more complex outputs.

Is there any other way to query the contents of my databases ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Athena is based on [Presto](https://prestosql.io). Presto provides `information_schema` schema and I checked and it is accessible in Athena.

You can run e.g. a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns;
```

to get a list of columns of all tables.

You can filter this by "database":

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = '<databasename>';
```

Note however that these types of queries are not necessarily very performant.

Comment: Now I am kicking myself !!  Thanks :)

Comment: @SimonB information_schema.tables has no inherent limitation of 100 relations in Trino (formerly Presto). If the limitation exists, it would probably either added by Athena or by a client tool.

Comment: Athena limitation on  information_schema.VIEWS; it only supports <=100 objects.
If your database has more than 100 tables/views, then this view will/can return zero results.
Confirmed limitation with Amazon support, but it is still undocumented in any official capacity.